# How to make eventlistener add image to my page?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a button. When I click the button, I want an image of a cat to be created. I have created a function to do this. I have added an event listener to the button that triggers the function when the button is clicked. But no such image is created. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="1">hello</button>
 <script>
function create(){
    var image= document.createElement("img")
    image.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
    q=tbn%3AANd9GcQeP6zBFWjK10gNYUK1kxM6I-AbF8vK_zPGSHrk38JzCb_5ZpRd&usqp=CAU"
    document.body.appendChild(image)
   }
   var element=document.getElementById("1")
   element.addEventListener("click", create)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please specify what error you are getting? The image should appear with this approach

Comment: can confirm @kokila. https://jsfiddle.net/wyq05ehc/

Comment: @Vedik you cannot have line break in between the image url of course. "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
    q=tbn%3AANd9GcQeP6zBFWjK10gNYUK1kxM6I-AbF8vK_zPGSHrk38JzCb_5ZpRd&usqp=CAU" won't work . "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQeP6zBFWjK10gNYUK1kxM6I-AbF8vK_zPGSHrk38JzCb_5ZpRd&usqp=CAU" will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That because the url got corrupted and  white space got introduced between `images?` and next line. Concat them using `+` or copy the url , try in the browser and then copy the same url from browser and put it between quotes

```js
function create() {
  var image = document.createElement("img")
  image.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?"+ 
"q=tbn%3AANd9GcQeP6zBFWjK10gNYUK1kxM6I-AbF8vK_zPGSHrk38JzCb_5ZpRd&usqp=CAU";
  document.body.appendChild(image)
}
var element = document.getElementById("1")
element.addEventListener("click", create)
```

```html
<button id="1">hello</button>
```

Comment: Ghehe you were a few seconds faster :P

Answer (score 1):

Add semicolons and remove the linebreak in the url:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="1">hello</button>
     <script>
    function create(){
        var image= document.createElement("img");
        image.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQeP6zBFWjK10gNYUK1kxM6I-AbF8vK_zPGSHrk38JzCb_5ZpRd&usqp=CAU";
        document.body.appendChild(image);
       }
       var element=document.getElementById("1");
       element.addEventListener("click", create);
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The semicolons are not required to make this work (And in fact make no functional difference to this particular piece of JS)